# Create list of Google Docs with modified date and modified user

Tags: google-docs

I'm responsible for about 200 documents, and 100 people who use these documents (two documents per person). Each user is responsible for regularly updating their two documents. I need to know if the users have indeed been updating their documents. Right now, the way I am doing this is by going into each document, looking at the revision history, and seeing if the assigned user made any changes. Ideally, I'd like to be able to download or create a list of all of my documents, with user names and dates for any modifications made.

Does anyone have any ideas?

In my fantasy world, I would end up with something like this:

[image: modification table]

Comment: There are basically three paths to follow: 1. Use Google Apps Script, 2. Use and add-on, 3. Use a third party app. Knowing this, the question looks too broad. Please add more details regarding your search/research efforts as this is suggested on [ask] and about the kind of solution that you are expecting.